# Emacs Org Mode: Export subheading with only certain :PROPERTIES: in HTML file

Tags: html, emacs, export, org-mode

How can I include only certain properties in a subheading HTML export?

My .emacs contains

> (setq org-export-with-properties '("CATEGORY" "CREATED"))

When exporting an H1 subheading to html, the resulting HTML file contains only the "CATEGORY" and "CREATED" properties as desired.  However, if I export an H2 subheading just under the H1 heading exported previously (no other changes made), the resulting HTML file does not contain any properties at all. Org manual exporting section states that:

> prop: Toggle inclusion of property drawers, or list the properties to include (org-export-with-properties).

So I tried including #+OPTIONS: prop:CATEGORY or prop:"CATEGORY" below H2 subheading being exported, no luck with either - both result in all properties being included in HTML file.

I'd rather not have to use #+OPTIONS: prop: But will if I must.

EXAMPLE:

```
* Projects
** Test Proj#1                                                      :PROJECT:
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CATEGORY: Proj1
   :CREATED: [2018-01-24 Wed]
   :EXPORT_FILE_NAME: ./projects-org-files/Proj1
   :EXPORT_TITLE: First Test Project
   :END:
*** Objective
    Object of Proj#1
*** Background
*** Log                                                            :noexport:
**** [2018-01-24 Wed]Did some stuff
*** Resolution
*** Summary Status
**** TODO Send TPF report to Bob
```

If I place cursor on H1 heading "Project" and press `C-e C-s h o`, I get the Properties and values in a box below the TestProj#1 header in the resulting HTML file.
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI7mO.png)

If I place cursor on H2 heading "TestProj#1" and press `C-e C-s h o`, I do not get the Properties and values in a box below the TestProj#1 header in the resulting HTML file.
[Unexpected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTvT6.png)

I have tried it on Emacs for Windows and on Emacs on my Linux box, and both give the same behavior.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question and show a short example? What properties does the subheading have? When I try what I think you are describing, it seems to work as expected. BTW, the OPTIONS prop syntax is `#+OPTIONS: prop:("CATEGORY" "CREATED")` - also don't forget to C-c C-c on the `#+OPTIONS` line to reevaluate it (or close and reopen the file).

Comment: I think I have figured out why I'm not getting what I'm wanting.... I'm putting the properties drawer under my project name (H2 heading), and when the project name subheading becomes the top level during the export of that subheading only, it gets parsed differently.  If I create a new H3 subheading, and put my properties drawer under there - it gets exported into the resulting HTML file.  Not what I'm wanting - guess I need to start figuring out how to change that behavior....  Thanks anyway.

Comment: For the record, I ended up using macro replacement: `{{{property(PROPERTY-NAME)}}}` below my H2 header to generate desired outcome in exported HTML file.